# ld to library without version information in Linux

Tags: linker, ld

When compiling a C/C++ program, is there a way to link to library exports in Linux without having ld embed the version information?

I am building a shared object that links to libxul.so in Firefox (it's a Firefox binary extension). I want to build my shared object and link to libxul.so so that at runtime, the loader does not care what version libxul.so is.

Right now, my output .so file has the following dependency:

```
readelf -V myext.so
  0x0080: Version: 1  File: libxul.so  Cnt: 1
  0x0090:   Name: xul24.0  Flags: none  Version: 9
```

(Note that it depends on the version 'xul24.0')

The exported functions do not change between Firefox versions. So, I want to remove this version instruction.

When attempting to load into Firefox 26, LD_DEBUG=file provides the following error:

```
/usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so: error: version lookup error:
version `xul24.0' not found (required by /.../myext.so) (fatal)
```

In the case of the Firefox 26 version of libxul.so, the version is `'xul26'`.

So, how can I prevent ld from embedding version information into my library?

Comment: When you link against libxul24 and then try to run against libxul26, the API and/or ABI of some functions will have changed, which is why you're not allowed to do that. This is an integrity check: the functions you want to use from one library are not necessarily the same in another library (which xul26 essentially is).

Comment: @mirabilos It's possible that build tools assign version number automatically even if nothing is changed. This is prompted to me by the fact library version is the same as the whole product version. Also I've seen this for some tools like gettext where there was no correlation between library version and functionality changes. But as soon as there is no guarantee API won't change, one still can't rely on safe loading of other library versions...

Comment: @Netch: sure, but he isn't the one generating the XUL library. In this case I believe it's a product-internal library where upstream doesn't even pretend to care about API/ABI stability (dunno if one's supposed to link against it in the first place). So I think that this is deliberate on the side of the M*zilla people.

Comment: There are other version compatibility checks that Mozilla enforces (namely the minVersion and maxVersion settings in the extension package), which are more fine-grained and flexible than the linkage version number. In any event, this is a deal-breaker for Linux since the same code works fine in Windows and Mac. A workaround where we use dlopen() and dynamically link to all of the libxul exports would be more costly than worthwhile.

Comment: @mirabilos Yep, I've seen it. Nevertheless I think such attaching a foreign library even with ABI change can be useful for academic purposes - proper toys shall be breakable, otherwise they won't teach:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to build the library as-desired, without the version information.

What I ended up doing was creating a dummy library with the appropriate exported symbols--without version (or soname) information--and linking to that dummy library while compiling and linking my library. At runtime, the loader loads the real library (libxul.so) without failing based on the versioning problems since my library does not contain version information for the real library. To figure out which exported symbols I needed, I first linked to the real libxul.so, then used `readelf --dyn-syms` to determine dwhich symbols were actually needed.

Where ARCH is 32 or 64  (for 32-bit or 64-bit compilation):
`gcc -o $ARCH/libxul.so -fPIC -shared -DM$ARCH -m$ARCH xulstubs.c`

xulstubs.c:

```
/*
 2: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND NS_Realloc@xul26 (2)
 3: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND NS_UTF16ToCString@xul26 (2)
 7: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND NS_CStringCloneData@xul26 (2)
13: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND NS_GetMemoryManager@xul26 (2)
...
 */
void NS_Realloc() {}
void NS_UTF16ToCString() {}
void NS_CStringCloneData() {}
void NS_GetMemoryManager() {}
/* ... etc. ... */
```

Now, the imported symbols from my library do not have the version appendage:

```
23: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND NS_Realloc
29: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND NS_UTF16ToCString
33: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND NS_CStringCloneData
37: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND NS_GetMemoryManager
```

and it runs as desired.

I would still like a more “elegant” solution, one that does not require creating a dummy library. If this is the only workaround using the standard toolchain, however, I can live with it.

Comment: Great solution and explanation. To avoid truncating long symbol names you can do `readelf --wide --dyn-syms`.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the most widespread GNU toolchain is considered, you can load any shared library without "lib" prefix and version suffix, but only directly using dlopen() from a code. Automatic loading during binary file start or another library loading won't work because, linker will find a library file, read its "soname" and "rpath" attributes from the library headers and apply them to find the library during the built target load. Soname is more important for the linker than the library file name. More so, at some systems, ldconfig can rename libraries in public search paths to match soname recorded inside (I've seen such on Linux).

A small example. Consider a file t.c where main() prints a value from library function and a library source file tt.c where the function returns a constant. Make them:

```
$ make clean; make
rm -f t t.o libtt.so tt.o
gcc -o libtt.so -shared -fPIC tt.c
gcc -o t t.c -L. -ltt
```

With these commands, ./t will fail because libtt.so isn't in public search paths, so LD_LIBRARY_PATH is needed to start it. But we can fix this:

```
$ gcc -o libtt.so -shared -fPIC tt.c
$ gcc -o t t.c -L. -ltt -Wl,-rpath=`pwd`
$ ldd ./t
./t:
        libtt.so => /var2/homes/netch/prog/tests/soname/libtt.so (0x80081a000)
        libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x800a1b000)
```

But, if I request another library name during its building, the search will fail:

```
$ gcc -o libtt.so -shared -fPIC tt.c -Wl,-soname=libtt2.so
$ gcc -o t t.c -L. -ltt -Wl,-rpath=`pwd`
$ ldd ./t
./t:
        libtt2.so => not found (0)
        libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x80081a000)
```

Note that, without seeing libtt.so, linker will fail because it doesn't know where to find unresolved links.

All this works for names other style than the described one, despite linker shows something strange:

```
$ gcc -o lybtt.so -shared -fPIC tt.c
$ gcc -o t t.c lybtt.so -Wl,-rpath=`pwd`
$ ./t
233
$ ldd ./t
./t:
        lybtt.so (0x80081a000)
        libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x800a1b000)
```

If you are library builder, you can name it without version and all tools will recognize this. But this is usually considered the bad style and is banned in recommendations. All libraries in public search paths are declared to have versions in their names, and this is strictly recommended for any software packaged not for home use.

For your question, if you really need to shoot yourself in foot, you can copy the libxul, change soname in it and put into the proper search path again. But I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. However, what I need to do is not shooting myself (or anyone else) in the foot. Surely there must be some way for my library to omit the name `xul24.0` when it is linked together...right? Conceptually it does not seem that hard.

Comment: Yes, there are such ways. 1. At run time, find the current version in the library directory and call dlopen() for it explicitly. You'll need also do dlsym() for each name to resolve it, because with automatic references this won't be linked properly. 2. You can cheat RTLD, unless the binary is sugid. If it's on FreeBSD, libmap.conf and LD_LIBMAP allow to substitute any library with another one. On all platforms, LD_LIBRARY_PATH gives another directory (but libraries in it shall be with the searched name.) 3. As already said, you can rewrite the library with changed soname.